# CSS z-index not working as expected

Tags: css, z-index

I recently started learning CSS3 Animations and I built a small page to test these animations. But I'm facing a problem regarding the z-index. In my test page there is an island on left-bottom corner and two waves on the bottom of the window. See [here](http://maffick.orgfree.com/test.maffick.transition/)

I want to put the island in between the two waves but It's not happening. The HTML structure is like this:

```
<div class="seashore">
    ...
    <img class="island" src="img/island.png" />
</div>

<div class="sea">
    <img class="wave1" src="img/w1.png" />
    <img class="boat" src="img/tboat.png" />
    <img class="wave2" src="img/w2.png" />
</div>
```

And The Respective CSS

```
/* Some CSS */

.seashore {
    position: absolute;
    left:0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 600px;
    z-index:990;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.island {
    position: absolute;
    left: -1px;
    bottom: 5%;;
    z-index: 1002;
}

.sea {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 60px;
    z-index:980;
    ....
}

.wave1 {
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 1000;
    ....
}

.wave2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: -16px;
    bottom: -3%;
    z-index: 1004;
    ....

}

.boat {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -15%;
    left: 75%;
    /*-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);*/
    z-index: 1003;
    ....
}
```

z-indexes are in this order:
*Sea (980) < Seashore(990) < Wave1(1000) < Island(1002) < Boat(1003) < Wave2(1004)*

I feel that this may be happening because both waves and island are contained in different parent container. But since z-index for both the containers are set to lowest, I think it should be working.

So my question is what is reason for this behaviour? And is there any workaround?

It would be best if you can provide any reference for the same. Thank You.

Comment: The waves and boat are all contained within a div with a lesser z-index.

Comment: @sideroxylon If z-index of div containing waves and boats is set to higher than it simply goes behind all the waves but not inbetween. I tried both the configruation, it either goes back or in front.

Comment: Please see both answers below.  I believe they address this issue.  At the moment, the waves are blocked by being in a div that sits behind the island.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the CSS for `.sea` and update the `position` and `z-index` of the waves:

```
.wave1 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 900;
    ....
}

.wave2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: -16px;
    bottom: -3%;
    z-index: 1003;
}
```

As mentioned in the answer above, you could just use 1,2 and 3 for `z-index`.

Result:

[image]

Comment: This will work at this moment but I require the waves to fixed on the bottom. Additionally I require sea class to apply some animations and properties as a whole.

Comment: Follow @Code Uniquely's advice above and put everything in one div and then stack them up as required.

Comment: I'm accepting this as an answer as It provides better workaround without changing structure much. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

You need to contain the elements in the same div, right now you have seashore and sea separate and so z-index effectively "restarts" inside each of those.

Seashore has a z-index of 909 and from that social balloon and island have 991 and 1002 (they could have just had 1 and 2) because its up from from the 909 of the seashore.

likewise with sea you start at 980 and then wave1 is 1000, boat is 1003 and wave 2 is 1004 (they could have been 1, 2 and 3 respectively).

just put all your moving elements inside the same single div and give them each an incremental z-index that puts them at the right level for your page.

try taking a look at the article [What No One Told You About Z-Index](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) by Philip Walton.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need both of them to be in seperate divs, as in future I planned for some additional animation and property on the whole sea. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: yes you can apply animations to classes and you can apply a class to more than one element so you could group things together like this  <img class="sea wave1"> and apply styles to "wave1" and "sea" separately